# How to do a RMSE-calculation for every subgroup of dataframe using a dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my_data:

```
p0  | country_ID | WinFlag | 
----------------------------
0.17| UK         | 0       |
0.85| GER        | 1       |
0.55| USA        | 0       |
0.25| USA        | 0       |
0.80| UK         | 1       |
```

etc.

I do succeed to caculate the RMSE from my_data with the code below:

```
test <- my_data %>%
      group_by(predic = round(p0, digits = 2)) %>%
      summarize(count = n(), wf = mean(WinFlag)) %>%
      mutate(vwap_err_sq = ((predic-wf)^2)*count)

      rmse_p0 <- sqrt(sum(test$vwap_err_sq) / sum(test$count))*100

 >   test:
          predic  count  wf    vwap_err_sq
            <dbl> <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
         1   0.04     6 0          0.0096 
         2   0.05     8 0.125      0.045  
         3   0.06    19 0.158      0.182  
         4   0.07    20 0.2        0.338
```

Next I try to calculate a specific RMSE for every country_ID in my_data.
Is it possible to do this with the pipe from dplyr?
I have tried to add group_by(country_ID) within the code above in several ways although I do not succeed to generate a specific RMSE for every country_ID.

Thanks a lot!

Below I have added a reproducible dataset with the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- data.frame(p0 = c(0.17,0.17,0.85,0.55,0.25,0.80),
                      country_ID=c("UK","UK","GER","USA","USA","UK"),
                      WinFlag=c(1,0,1,0,0,1))


test <- my_data %>%
  group_by(predic = round(p0, digits = 2)) %>%
  mutate(count = 1) %>%
  mutate(wf = mean(WinFlag)) %>%
  mutate(vwap_err_sq = ((predic-wf)^2)*1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(country_ID) %>%
  mutate(rmse_p0 = sqrt(sum(vwap_err_sq*count) / sum(count))*100)
```

Comment: Are you looking for one `RMSE` per `country_ID`?

Comment: @ lab_rat_kid Yes. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to carry `country_ID` forward from your first `group_by` to then `group_by` a second time.

EDIT:

As per comments, to get the `mean(WinFlag)` we must leave this until we have done `group_by(country_ID)` and we will have to get rid of `summarize` as this gets rid of other columns.

```
my_data <- data.frame(p0 = c(0.17,0.85,0.55,0.25,0.80),
                     country_ID=c("UK","GER","USA","USA","UK"),
                     WinFlag=c(0,1,0,0,1))

> my_data
    p0 country_ID WinFlag
1 0.17         UK       0
2 0.85        GER       1
3 0.55        USA       0
4 0.25        USA       0
5 0.80         UK       1

test <- my_data %>%
  group_by(predic = round(p0, digits = 2)) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(country_ID) %>%
  mutate(wf = mean(WinFlag)) %>%
  mutate(vwap_err_sq = ((predic-wf)^2)*count) %>%
  mutate(rmse_p0 = sqrt(sum(vwap_err_sq) / sum(count))*100)

> test
# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Groups:   country_ID [3]
     p0 country_ID WinFlag predic count    wf vwap_err_sq rmse_p0
  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1  0.17 UK               0   0.17     1   0.5      0.109     31.5
2  0.85 GER              1   0.85     1   1        0.0225    15  
3  0.55 USA              0   0.55     1   0        0.303     42.7
4  0.25 USA              0   0.25     1   0        0.0625    42.7
5  0.8  UK               1   0.8      1   0.5      0.09      31.5
```

It still gives you the original number of rows, but the `rmse` uses data from grouped `country_ID`s

EDIT:

And if you just wanted the `country_ID` along with the `rmse_p0` then this works:

```
rmse <- test[match(unique(test$country_ID),test$country_ID),c("country_ID","rmse_p0")]

> rmse
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   country_ID [3]
  country_ID rmse_p0
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 UK            31.5
2 GER           15  
3 USA           42.7
```

Comment: @ lab_rat_kid thank you. That is better than I did so far. Although it seems to me GER is calculated correct, while UK is not. If I do manual it is : SQRT(((0.5 - 0.17)^2 + (0.5 - 0.8)^2)/2) * 100 = 31.54. Can it be that takes 0 and 1 instead of the mean of 0 and 1?

Comment: The results you have for `test` at the top are not what are produced from your sample data and code. That's why. I guess your example of `test` above is from a larger set of data.

Comment: That is correct. In my example above I did not show all data. I should had made the example that way indeed. Although in your example all data is known. I will try further tomorrow. Probably you have put me on the right track enough so I can solve it by myself. I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: I see why...the `mean(WinFlag)` is when after the first `group_by`...so it's not actually done a mean. It's the mean of one number! 

Comment: :-) I will check and let you know.

Comment: I've got it now...give me a sec to update the answer.

Comment: @ lab_rat_kid There was still an issue that the vwap_err_sq was not based on the mean winflag for the specific p0 value. I have modified your code and posted under my question (with a new dataset). I suppose my initial question was not clear. Thank you for your help putting me on the right track! If you copy it to your answer I delete it from my question. Thanks